# How should I integrate 5K training with bodyweight exercises?

Tags: abdominals, back, treadmill, couchto5k

I have found a C25K plan that is 100% interval training with full runs only during the last few weeks. However, I don’t just want to be able to run a 5k. I also want to eventually get 6 pack abs so I am exercising my abs and back(back is mainly for avoiding a muscle imbalance) starting at 1 set of 10 reps for both and adding exercises every 3 weeks.

So, obviously, I will need protein but as far as the exercises, how should I integrate the 5K training with abs and back exercises?

The 5K training is every other day for 3 days of the week. I have noticed me being able to do bodyweight exercises daily without soreness unless I go past 10 reps per day the first week, even just a couple reps past it like 12 will cause me to potentially pull my muscles so 1 set of 10 is the limit for the first week, 2 sets of 10 for the second week, and 3 sets of 10 for the third week.

I will start my 5K training by running in place just to get the endurance for the time and then start using a treadmill to train myself for hills up to the maximum incline that my treadmill can get to(which I do believe is 30 degrees).

Comment: Are you looking to combine running with abs/back workouts?  What type of workouts are you doing?

Comment: I am starting with situps and back-ups(basically an abdominal stretch but for the purpose of exercising my back) both at 10 reps/day. I plan on adding more bodyweight exercises once I get the previous exercises to 3 sets of 10 and increasing each exercise up to 3 sets of 10 reps slowly, like at most adding a set of 10 after a week. I wouldn't mind having some extra muscle in my abdomen and in my back but my main purpose of exercising is to lose weight because I am overweight and even with a healthy controlled diet I still lose like a few pounds, not much compared to what I need to lose.